# 15.10 system install hang

Tags: system-installation

I have a machine that has happily been running 14.04 for ages, until I borked it (it no longer lets me log into a GUI desktop - logs available if interested).  I decided to try a fresh install of 15.10 from DVD (made from a .ISO I had MD5SUM checked), but it hangs after about 2 minutes while showing me dots.  The coloured dot stops moving.  DVD has been verified, memory has been tested and is OK.

I have tried a reinstall of 14.04 from USB, but the result was the same.

The machine is:
NOVATECH ELITE N1586 - 15.6" INTEL I7 4700 MOBILE PROCESSOR - 16GB DDR3 MEMORY - 256GB MSATA DRIVE - 1TB SATA HARD DRIVE - DVD WRITER - NVIDIA GTX 780M GRAPHICS

BIOS is AMI 2.15.1236

All my installs hitherto have gone without much problem, so I have no idea how to debug / proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install Ubuntu 15.10 by following these instructions ... Boot from the Ubuntu installation media.

When the **boot menu** appears : Highlight **Try Ubuntu without installing** and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add the `nouveau.modeset=0` parameter to the end of the linux line ... Then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

When having entered the desktop start the installation process, once completed restart the PC.

When the **GRUB boot menu** appears : Highlight the **Ubuntu menu entry** and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add the `nouveau.modeset=0` parameter to the end of the linux line ... Then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

Now install the latest official NVIDIA drivers and Optimus support.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Enter your user name and password.

Execute these commands :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

In case you have to adjust which card to use in BIOS select **NVIDIA** or  **switchable graphics mode**.
Open **NVIDIA X Server Settings** -> **Prime Profiles** to switch between the intel and NVIDIA GPUs.

Comment: This has worked for me, with the slight wrinkle that it failed first time when I had the two checkboxes ticked on the install process (download updates & install additional software).