# Ubuntu 15.10 freeze seconds after startup

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 15.10

I seem to have a similar problem to [this helpful post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696671/15-10-system-install-hang), but I cannot proceed.  I have a dual-boot 15.10 installation with WIN10 on an M2 disk.  I am keen to work with 15.10 since I had Wifi driver problems I could not resolve easily in 14.04.4.  I can boot into the installed 15.10 or Try Ubuntu 15.10 on USB no problems. About 10 seconds after loading the desktop (ie after the purple startup screen), everything freezes, nothing works (keyboard, mouse, touchpad), but the display is unchanged.  This is a brand new install.  Sounds like drivers I guess, but I got no joy pressing the E key during startup (see other post), and anticipate that I cannot proceed anyway once I get the desktop. Very grateful for advice.

Relevant system details are: Metabox Prime P640RE laptop, 14.0" WQHD 3K 2560x1440 IPS Matte 60Hz LED, Nvidia GTX 970M, i7-6700HQ, 32GB DDR4 2133MHZ, Samsung 950 Pro 512GB M.2 PCIe SSD, Killer 1535 AC WIFI.

Edit: I should mention that I verified checksums, installed the 64bit desktop version and transferred to USB with Win32DiskImager.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem.  It required something a little different than @cl-netbox described on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696671/15-10-system-install-hang), though I did try the described sequence (including adding `noveau-modeset=0` to the first line after pressing E on the **Try Ubuntu without installing** option).  When the Unity desktop had loaded, and before it froze, I pressed Ctrl + Alt + F1. The nvidia-355 driver would not install, neither did the 361.28 driver that the [nvidia website](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/98373/en-us) suggested was appropriate for the GTX970 graphics card on Linux-64.

I ran the command `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` and noticed that the installed driver was 352. I then ran `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`.  I repeated `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` and noted that the installed driver was still 352.  Then I rebooted, and was treated to a fully functioning Unity desktop.  So far no freezes or other issues.

I assume that the autoinstall fixed something, somewhere.  I can appreciate that different hardware and installations require different solutions.  Apologies I could not regurgitate the full terminal outputs, but perhaps this will help someone with a quick fix.